# How to read strings and float on the same line from a file in C

Tags: c

I want to read a file in C, that has some data about employees from a company. I'm kind a new to C so I have no idea how to do that.

Each line of the file has some strings and by the end of each line, there's a float number.

I know the size of each string. For example, the first string is a Name and will have a size of 70:

`Giovani Albuquerc inoval ciano`

So, in the file, I will have the name of the employee, and the rest of the name is composed by spaces.

I searched and saw people using `fscanf()`, but with `fscanf()` I can't get the whole name, because the string name can have multiple spaces between, first and second name, third name, etc.

Can someone give me some ideas, please?

Comment: And where is the float?

Comment: The float is going to be after all the strings

Comment: I have Name A B C D E F 1.20

Comment: A B C D E F are differents strings that i already know the size

Comment: You could probably use fgets, then use string operations to get your required output. Like, say, get individual words from the string. The last 'word' will be your float. atof it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char tmp[100]="";
    float x;
    int i=100;
    
    fp = fopen("name_float.txt","r");
    if (fp){
        while (i != EOF){
            i = fscanf(fp," %s",tmp); // Space before %s skips leading whitespace
            if (i != EOF){
                x = atof(tmp);
                if (x == 0){ // not a proper float
                    printf("Name component: %s\n",tmp);
                } else {
                    printf("Float (last field in the line): %f\n\n",x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

With `name_float.txt` as follows:

```
Alan Brian Carl Dan 1.2
Emma Fiona Gregory 3.4
```

The output is shown below:

```
Name component: Alan
Name component: Brian
Name component: Carl
Name component: Dan
Float (last field in the line): 1.200000

Name component: Emma
Name component: Fiona
Name component: Gregory
Float (last field in the line): 3.400000
```